# Changing color components in Java

Tags: java, graphics, colors, components, rgb

Is there a way to change the individual color components in Java graphics programming (apart from the brighter() and darker() methods? For example, if I create a Color object with r,g,b color components and then wish to modify one of them is there a way to do so?

```
Color x = new Color(255,0,0);
```

Is there a way to quickly change one of the individual color components?

Comment: i've tried setting variables as the rgb components and using getRed(), getBlue(), and getGreen() but java gives me an error

Comment: for Color, you'll end up creating a new color object always, because the color is always defined by the constructor. That's also how brighter() and darker() methods work internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually change an existent Color object. To have a different one, you have to create a another Color object because the object is always defined by the constructor values. This is also how darker() and brighter() are internally implemented. Take a look

```
public Color brighter() {
    int r = getRed();
    int g = getGreen();
    int b = getBlue();
    int alpha = getAlpha();

    /* From 2D group:
     * 1. black.brighter() should return grey
     * 2. applying brighter to blue will always return blue, brighter
     * 3. non pure color (non zero rgb) will eventually return white
     */
    int i = (int)(1.0/(1.0-FACTOR));
    if ( r == 0 && g == 0 && b == 0) {
        return new Color(i, i, i, alpha);
    }
    if ( r > 0 && r < i ) r = i;
    if ( g > 0 && g < i ) g = i;
    if ( b > 0 && b < i ) b = i;

    return new Color(Math.min((int)(r/FACTOR), 255),
                     Math.min((int)(g/FACTOR), 255),
                     Math.min((int)(b/FACTOR), 255),
                     alpha);
}
```

and

```
public Color darker() {
    return new Color(Math.max((int)(getRed()  *FACTOR), 0),
                     Math.max((int)(getGreen()*FACTOR), 0),
                     Math.max((int)(getBlue() *FACTOR), 0),
                     getAlpha());
}
```